# Sufficient condtions for swapping limits in a sequence of sets.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Hello I'm struggling with a large proof in a paper I'm working on but my question basically comes down to this:

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a sequence of sets $(X_\gamma)_{\gamma\in\mathbb{R}}\subseteq\mathbb{R^n}$ and a set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ such that $X_\gamma \rightarrow X$ as $\gamma \searrow 0.$
Now for $\delta > 0$, define $X_{\gamma, \delta}:= \{x \in X_\gamma: f(x) \geq \delta\}$ and $X_\delta := \{x \in X: f(x) \geq \delta\}$.
I need to show that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\gamma\searrow 0} X_{\gamma, \delta} = X_{\delta}.
\end{equation}

What would be sufficient conditions for this to happen and why?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by the limit of a sequence of sets?

Comment: Well, in my example the sequence $X_\gamma$ is increasing as $\gamma \searrow 0$, so $\lim_{\gamma \searrow 0} X_\gamma = \bigcup X_\gamma$

Comment: If the limit is just a union, isn't this true for any $X_\delta$ and any $f$?